# Differences between Bitmaps and BufferedImages

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bufferedimage

I am trying to port some code from a regular Java program into the Android platform. Unfortunately, a significant part of the program involves manipulating images, and Java's AWT was taken away from me. I am trying to replace `awt.BufferedImage` with `Bitmap`, and was hoping that the only differences between the two classes would be their interfaces. I read some of the documentation, and it looked like that is true, but after wrapping all of the image stuff into a nice little class and testing almost-the-same code on both my development machine and an actual phone, one program works and the other does not. So:

The encoding for color does not change - right? It is still `0xAARRGGBB` - right?

The images themselves are not changed - right? When I put an image into `res/drawable`, it is exactly the same image. Most notably, they don't alter the resolution in any way -  right?

Accessing the pixels is essentially the same - right? I essentially replaced all of my `get/setRGB(x,y,RGB)` with `get/setPixel(x,y,color)`. There are no changes to the method of indexing into the grid - is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: when opening the image, I failed to create a `BitmapFactory.Options()` with `inDither` set to false. The `BitmapFactory` then failed to produce an exact copy, putting some alterations in the resulting `Bitmap` in order to make it more pleasing for display.